# Using PHP strtotime() function

Tags: php, javascript, time

I'm getting an external RSS Feed Post in different website, what I noticed is that they all have a different format of Publish Date.
Some uses a formatting like this:

```
2012-04-09T08:23:07Z

Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43  0000
```

There are still lots of format but I was just showing you two examples.

Now, I want everything to have a uniform format, so i'm using strtotime(). Here's my code:

```
$date = "2012-04-09T08:23:07Z";
date( "F d, Y", strtotime( $date ) );
/* Result: April 09, 2012 */
```

My problem here is the second format `Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43  0000`

There is a 0000 at the last which makes the strtotime() act weird.

```
$date = "Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43  0000";
 date( "F d, Y", strtotime( $date ) );
 /* Result: April 06, 0000 */
```

Obviously the result should be April 06,2012.

My question here is that how can I not let strtotime() act weird when it detects a format that has a 0000 at the last. Any idea how to do this? Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any other datetime formats that cause a problem? If this is the only one, you may just have to special case strings that end in "0000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have a formatting issue:

```
Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43  0000
```

Notice the two spaces before `0000`? That's not a coincidence. The original is probably this:

```
Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43 +0000
```

Which is generated with `gmdate(DATE_RFC822)`. In URI's, the `+` symbol often gets translated to a space. I think that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that one too, there's a + symbl before the 0000, but when I stored it in the database the + symbol is gone, is it because I tried to mysql_real_escape_string() it?

Comment: Nope, `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't escape `+` characters, so perhaps this happens when you extract it from the XML?

Answer (score 1):

How about just stripping the "0000"? Something like:

> $date=str_replace("0000", "", $date);

Comment: RFC822 doesn't indicate GMT as a prerequisite, so it could also end with `0800`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php 
$date = "Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43 0000";

 if (strtotime($date) !== false) 
 {
 $timestamp = strtotime($date);
     echo date( "F d, Y", $timestamp );
 } 
 else 
 {
     echo "error";
 }

 ?>
```

for $date = "Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43  0000";
outputs error.

$date = "Fri, 06 Apr 2012 01:25:43";
gives output.